# two list on one screen, android, fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to do something like this:
1) I have SPINNER. When I choose any position...
2) I want to show other list (at the same screen) with more options.

Actually I've done something like this to test it, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? It's in class extend Fragment. Of course MakeDrugsList() doesn't show what I want, but it's version to test this clue. I want to change it when BOTH lists starts to work. And before I made "MakeDrugsList()" spinner was working.

```
void makeSpinner(){
     spn = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, diseas2);
        spn.setAdapter(adapter2);
         spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                            int position = spn.getSelectedItemPosition();
                            makeListOfDrugs();

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    }
                );
 }

 void makeListOfDrugs(){
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;  
        String cars[] = {"Mercedes", "Fiat", "Ferrari", "Aston Martin", "Lamborghini", "Skoda", "Volkswagen", "Audi", "Citroen"};
        ArrayList<String> carL = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        carL.addAll( Arrays.asList(cars) ); 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, carL);
        drugsList.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done. Unless you do it in two seperate fragments, but I'm not familiar with fragments, so someone else will have to clarify. As a general rule, list views are populated by the OS based on a layout and pumped through an adapter. I don't think the OS would like to share the activity space with seperate listviews. As an aside, can I have some Aston Martin. Sounds like some cracking drugs! ;)

Comment: It works! I had really stupid mistake - wrong definition of listview. Now question is not actual :)